# How to schedule the schedulable class for every one minute in salesforce?

Tags: schedulebatch

can you please give me the example of schedule apex class  for every one minute .How to solve the above scenario.please give some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more why you want to schedule this every minute?

And you can do like as below : which executes every 10 minutes and

```
scheduledApexClassName m = new scheduledApexClassName();

String seconds = ’0′; //Execute at Zero Seconds
String minutes = ’10,20,30,40,50′; //Execute at every 10th minute of hour
String hours = ‘*’; // Execute Every Hour
String dayOfMonth = ‘*’; // Execute Every Day of the Month
String month = ’11′; //Execute only in November(11)
String dayOfWeek = ‘?’; //Execute on all 7 days of the Week
String year = ’2009′; //Execute only for year 2009

//Seconds Minutes Hours Day_of_month Month Day_of_week optional_year
String sch = seconds + ‘ ‘ + minutes + ‘ ‘ + hours + ‘ ‘ + dayOfMonth + ‘ ‘ + month + ‘ ‘ + dayOfWeek + ‘ ‘ + year;
//String sch = ’0 10,20,30,40,50 * * 11 ? 2009′;

system.schedule(‘Registration Report’, sch, m);
```

Thanks
sfdev

Comment: How to write the schedule apex class for every one minute. please give me one example